# How to find MinDate / MaxDate If there is a gap in the Date sequence in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by

My dataset looks like this and I need to generate the StartDate (Min), EndDate(Min) by grouping them by Name and Date columns. When Type changes, the group by logic should break and take Max date till there.

| Name | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | xx | 1/1/2018 |
| A | xx | 1/2/2018 |
| A | yy | 1/3/2018 |
| A | xx | 1/4/2018 |
| A | xx | 1/5/2018 |
| A | xx | 1/6/2018 |

The output would be like:

| Name | Type | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | xx | 1/1/2018 | 1/2/2018 |
| A | yy | 1/3/2018 | 1/3/2018 |
| A | xx | 1/4/2018 | 1/6/2018 |

Answer (score 1):

The challenge in this case is to identify all target groups by the columns `Name` and `Type` taking into account the gaps. As a possible solution, you can use an additional grouping expression based on the difference between `Row_Number` ordered by `Date` and `Row_Number` ordered by `Date` with `Partion by Name, Type`.

```
With A As (
Select Name, [Type], [Date], 
        Row_Number() Over (Order by [Date]) As Num, 
        Row_Number() Over (Partition by Name, [Type] Order by [Date]) As Num_1
From Tbl)
Select Name, [Type], 
       Convert(VarChar(10), Min([Date]), 103) As StartDate,
       Convert(VarChar(10), Max([Date]), 103) As EndDate
From A
Group by Name, [Type], Num - Num_1
Order by StartDate
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac3e691f2d6af8e1843928c54855031f)

| Name | Type | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | xx | 01/01/2018 | 01/02/2018 |
| A | yy | 01/03/2018 | 01/03/2018 |
| A | xx | 01/04/2018 | 01/06/2018 |

Answer (score 1):

Below approach would be bit clumsy yet fetches the desired output. The buckets are partitioned based on the date (day) difference.

```
declare @tbl table(name varchar(5),type varchar(5),[date] date)

insert into @tbl
values('A','xx','1/1/2018')
,('A','xx','1/2/2018')
,('A','yy','1/3/2018')
,('A','xx','1/4/2018')
,('A','xx','1/5/2018')
,('A','xx','1/6/2018')

select distinct name,type
,min(date)over(partition by name,type,diffmodified order by diffmodified) as [StartDate]
,max(date)over(partition by name,type,diffmodified order by diffmodified) as [EndDate]
from(
select *
,case when max(diff)over(partition by name,type order by [date]) > 1
then max(diff)over(partition by name,type order by [date]) else diff end as [diffmodified]
from(
select *, 
isnull(DATEDIFF(day, lag([date],1)
over(partition by name,type order by [date]), [date] ),1)[diff]
from
@tbl)
t)t
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this clarify you.

```
select Name,Type,min(date) as StartDate,max(date) as EndDate
from Table_Name
group by Type,Name
```